# Problems with opening local html with watir

Tags: html, internet-explorer, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a local html file on my C drive
and I am trying to open it and click on a button.
Html file looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <div id="second">
            <div id="third">
                <button id="button">Text</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="txt">Not clicked yet</p>
    <script type="javascript">
        var par = document.getElementById('txt');
        function clicked() {
            if (par.innerText == 'Clicked') {
                par.innerHTML = 'Clicked Again';
            } else {
                par.innerHTML = 'Clicked';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I am trying to use following code to open the file and click on a button:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
browser.goto "file://C:\\test.html"
browser.button(id: 'button').click
```

but I am getting following exception:

```
Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException: browser window was closed
```

if I go to to any other non local URLs everything works fine.
Does anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

My system params:

```
Windows 7 64 bit, IEDrvierServer 2.49, IE11
```

Comment: Do you have to prepend `file://` to the URL?  I vaguely recall that was needed for `watir-classic` (or `watir` when using IE), and you are using `watir-webdriver`.

Comment: Yes, otherwise it appends http:\\www in front of url

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you should use forward slashes, and note the 3 forward slashes at the beginning: `file:///C:/Documents/Foo`

Also, you should update to the latest IEDriverServer 2.53.1 (use the 32 bit version).

If this doesn't fix it, please edit the question to include a full backtrace.